# Why My android App doesn't Create folder at /data/data/my.package.com

Tags: android, directory, android-image, android-package-managers, android-database

I have installed an Android app on my phone which I have created myself on java. The App got successfully installed on the device but I am not able to locate the package where it has installed.It is not located on the /data/data/my.package.com directory as well, There is no any directory created for my package name at data folder.

How to find the path of the installed application Please help?

And I download some image files form server. I want them to put them in to /data/data/my.package.com folder for delete when app uninstall.

Here is my downloading code.

```
private class DownloadImage extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File dir = new File (sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/fog/images");
        // Make sure the Pictures directory exists.
        dir.mkdirs();
        File destinationFile = new File(dir, "fog"+params[1]);
        String filepath = null;
        try{
            URL url = new URL("http://admin.mindshaperapp.com/uploads/"+params[0]+".jpg");

            HttpURLConnection conection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            conection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conection.setRequestProperty("Content-length", "0");
            conection.setUseCaches(false);
            conection.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
            conection.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            conection.setReadTimeout(15000);
            conection.connect();

            int status = conection.getResponseCode();

            switch (status) {
                case 200:
                case 201:
                    FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(destinationFile);
                    InputStream inputStream = conection.getInputStream();
                    int totalSize = conection.getContentLength();
                    int downloadedSize = 0;
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                    int bufferLength = 0;
                    while ( (bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0 )
                    {
                        fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
                        downloadedSize += bufferLength;
                    }
                    fileOutput.close();
                    if(downloadedSize==totalSize) filepath = destinationFile.getPath();
                    return filepath;

            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

I want to locate all images and application, the place where delete all things automatically when uninstall the application. please help

Comment: Your phone needs to be rooted to see that `/data/data` folder.

Comment: Thank you @jankigadhiya, My device is already rooted. I can see other app folders in the data/data folder. But this one is not there

Answer (score 2):

In your code, you're explicitly accessing the external storage; you'd want to access internal storage. To do that, change:

```
File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
```

to

```
File sdCard = Environment.getFilesDir();
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Hope this will help. And as well Do you have any idea why my app is not visible in data/data folder. Where are the data base and other app files locate?